# Cloning buttons from HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use a SaaS job board and the "jobs" page of job board doesn't have a footer according to Google Jobs requirements. The job board has an option to insert CSS or JS code for all the website and a footer HTML section to insert HTML.

So the issue is that my two buttons don't appear on the jobs page as it doesn't have a footer. I'm trying to let them appear by JS.

Here is what I have:

HTML buttons in the footer:

```js
// Find the buttons in the main page's footer
const mainPageButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".add_zakaz, .add_zakaz2");

// Iterate over each button and clone them
mainPageButtons.forEach(button => {
  const clonedButton = button.cloneNode(true);
  // Append the cloned button to the end of the document body
  document.body.appendChild(clonedButton);
});
```

```css
.add_zakaz {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 65px;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.add_zakaz2 {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 600px;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <a class="add_zakaz" href="https://move2usajobs-com.forum2x2.ru/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img src="https://movetousajobs.mysmartjobboard.com/files/userfiles/forum-removebg-preview.png" alt="buttons"></a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a class="add_zakaz2" href="https://movetousajobs.mysmartjobboard.com?msopen=/member/sign_in"><img src="https://movetousajobs.mysmartjobboard.com/files/userfiles/ezgif.com-gif-maker-removebg-preview.png"></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Please let me understand why it doesn't work. Thank you!

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how simply cloning the buttons will fix the issue? You seem to already have the buttons. It sounds like you need an actual footer, which you don't address here. Or I could be completely misunderstanding.